# 5.62.0 configuration options?

Tags: upgrade

The [release notes for 5.62.0](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/release-notes/5.62.0.md) say that this update requires attention to configuration options but I can't see anything more about what it is that requires attention. There's no mention of 5.62.0 on the [version-specific upgrade tasks](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/) page. Is there something I need to pay attention to when upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When that's mentioned in the release notes, it's not that everyone must make configuration changes, but it's good to read through and pay attention to what items mention configuration changes, because choices have been made, new options added, etc.

In the case of 5.62.0, the things I'd look out for are:

- if you have custom code depending upon legacy custom searches, that's now in an extension (enabled by default, but still something that could be an issue)
- the enabled components (e.g. CiviMail, CiviCase) now take effect across all domains in a CiviCRM installation rather than as separate options for each domain
- the warning that will appear if you have activity revisions in CiviCase

As you can see in each of those issues, developers and reviewers take care that for most sites most things are smooth/consistent, but it could still come as a surprise if you do have less common configurations.

Comment: Thank you. It'd be helpful if there was something in the notes that explained why that question was flagged in the synopsis - similar to how Drupal lists the direct issue links for any changes to default.settings.php, .htaccess, etc under a 'major changes' heading.